# How to replace Nokia Lumia 1520 screen?

Tags: lumia

Yesterday I drop my Lumia 1520 to the ground in an accident and the screen broken, then I went to the repair shop and it cost really much. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could get a replacement screen from eBay or somewhere and put it in yourself. This is probably gonna cost you around $40 to $50 including all the tools you need. 
HOWEVER please only do this if you're really comfortable with disassembling your phone and you know what you're doing. Having broken a phone myself this way I can say that this is not easy to do right. Especially since you can't do any screen calibration yourself.

Giving the phone to Nokia services should be around $100, right? For me the difference would be small enough to remain on the safe side.

Comment: ...and consider a protective case to avoid breaking it again...

Comment: I purchased a complete screen assy for my 1520 due to the digitizer giving me random ghost touch issues. The screen received from ebay seller seemed to be exact replacement. Upon doing the swap, which I followed step by step from you tube, the screen did not scroll smoothly. And worse, when the screen timed out, it would deactivate the touch screen altogether, requiring a reboot every time to get it working again. I ended up swapping back to my old screen, which is working the same as it did before the swap. So at least I am back to square one and not square zero with an unusable phone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also the teardown of ifixit.com helps you to disassemble
https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nokia+Lumia+1520+Teardown/23924

there is also a YouTube Video about how to repair:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIVJxqfW27Q&noredirect=1